# How can I get my Ubuntu 10.04 Hyper-V VM to recognize the virtual networking hardware?

Tags: networking, 10.04, virtualization, hyper-v

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu, being primarily a Windows developer for the past 20 years. However, we've been using Redmine hosted on an Ubuntu VM to manage our development tickets. The VM was hosted by another company, but recently my company decided to take over hosting of the VM in-house.

I imagine we will be hosting the VM in Microsoft Azure, so I asked the company to export their VM as a VHD file, which they did. It was previously a Citrix VM, apparently.

Now that I have the VHD, I was able to create a new Hyper-V VM on my local machine and attached the VHD to it. I can start the machine and log in to Ubuntu using the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Connection app. However, once I do I am unable to access the network (either local or internet). From what little I know of Linux, it appears the VM doesn't recognize the network hardware.

When I do `ifconfig` on the box, I get the following:

```
# ifconfig
lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:225.0.0.0
        inet6 addr:  ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric: 1
        RX packets:284 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:284 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:108001 (108.0 KB)  TX bytes:108001 (108.0 KB)
```

(apologies if there are any typos in that. Copy-and-paste from the VM isn't working so I had to type it manually).

When I do `lshw -class network` I get no results.

When I do `netstat -i` I get the following:

```
Kernel Interface table
IFace  MTU Met  RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
lo     16436    0     409    0      0      0     409    0      0      LRU
```

(again, apologies for any typos).

So it seems to me that the system doesn't even see the network hardware. I have the VM set to use a virtual switch associated with my Wifi adapter. This setup is working for my Windows VMs on the same machine.

Just to make sure incompatibilty with Ubuntu wasn't the problem, I created a new blank VM with the same hardware settings and an empty hard drive, and did a fresh install of Ubuntu using a downloaded ISO. On this fresh Ubuntu machine, the network and internet access just fine. When I do `lshw -class network` on the fresh machine I get the following:

```
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    physical id: 1
    logical name: eth0
    serial: 00:15:5d:00:66:17
    capabilities: ethernet physical
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=hv_netvsc firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.253 link=yes multicast=yes
```

So, the Wifi virtual switch I have set up the VM to use is working and can at least potentially work in Ubuntu. I need to figure out how to get my former Citrix VM to recognize the network hardware. There is a version difference between the two OSes. The networkless VM is Ubuntu 10.04.4. The fresh install that is working on my network is Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Below is a screenshot of the VM settings from Hyper-V manager for the non-connected Ubuntu 10.04.4 VM.

[image: Hyper-V VM Settings]

I'm not sure what I can do to fix this. Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks.